# How to tell the client has end the connection during IPC using QLocalSocket?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two programs doing IPC using QLocalSocket & QLocalServer, I have managed to implement the connection and send the data successfully.

However, for the QLocalServer side, how can I know a connection is ended by client (like the client program quit.)?

So that I could release the resource of corresponding socket on server side?

Comment: Reading from a disconnected socket or sending data over disconnected socket should trigger an error.

Comment: In that way, I will need to constantly read/write to that socket. Is there any other method which does not require that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the `void QLocalSocket::disconnected()` signal from QLocalHost to a slot in your class:

```
connect(mySocket, &QLocalSocket::disconnected, this, &MyClass::socketDisconnected, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Or you can connect to the stateChange (for more detailed version), something like:

```
// Connect like this
connect(mySocket, &QLocalSocket::stateChanged, this, &MyClass::socketNewState, Qt::QueuedConnection);

// Implement a slot that handles the various states...
MyClass::socketNewState(QLocalSocket::LocalSocketState socketState)
{
   qDebug() << "New state is " << socketState << endl;
}
```